# Is acetylene IR active?

Tags: spectroscopy, ir-spectroscopy

I've a very straight forward question, I'm confused because I've been told that a atom which has a oscillating transient/permanent dipole is IR active. But there are few asymmetric stretching/bending modes in acetylene? So, why does my teacher say it's IR inactive?

Comment: IR activity is not a property of an atom, nor that of a molecule. It is a property of a particular oscillation.

Comment: @IvanNeretin _This_ should have been the answer. And its clear, concise, to the point, too.

Comment: Clear as it may be, my comment is way too short for an answer.

Comment: You may find some vibration frequencies of acetylene [here](https://www.cup.uni-muenchen.de/ch/compchem/vib/vib2.html#:~:text=Acetylene%20is%20a%20highly%20symmetric,D(infinite)h%20symmetry.&text=Due%20to%20its%20center%20of,moment%20will%20be%20IR%20active.).

Comment: Also, vibration patterns (active and inactive) [here](https://www.chem.purdue.edu/jmol/vibs/c2h2.html) with animations.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it has an IR spectra to me:

[image]

Source: https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C74862&Type=IR-SPEC&Index=1